# How to override a plugin function wrapped in a class?

Tags: plugins, functions

The class is from someone else's WP plugin and I want to adapt one of the functions from that class (there are more functions).

The (edited) original code:

```
class some_class {
    private function get_section_url() {
        $full_url = add_query_arg( 'action', 'action-name', admin_url( 'users.php' ) );
        $relative_url = str_replace( get_site_url(), '', $full_url );
        return $relative_url;
    }
}
```

I want to override the above function with this:

```
function get_section_url() {
    $full_url = add_query_arg( 'action', 'action-name', admin_url( 'users.php' ) );
    return $full_url;
}
```

How to achieve this? I tried some suggested solutions ([here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173909/how-to-override-a-theme-function-within-a-class-using-a-plugin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806668/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-function-within-a-php-class)), but without success.

**UPDATE**

The original function is called in this way (only from the same class):

```
public function parent_file($parent_file) {
    global $current_screen, $submenu_file, $typenow;
    if ( $current_screen->base == 'users' && request_param( 'action' ) == 'action-name' ) {
        $parent_file = 'parent.php';
        $submenu_file = $this->get_section_url();
        $typenow = 'hide-users-menu';
    }
    return $parent_file;
}

public function menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $capability = admin_capability();
    if ( current_user_can( $capability ) ) {
        $url = $this->get_section_url();
    $submenu['parent.php'][] = array( __( 'Menu Item Title' ), $capability, $url );
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that function called in the code?

Comment: @czerspalace I updated the question.

Comment: and how is called `menu()` ?

Comment: @mmm I found this: `add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'menu'));`

Answer (score 1):

if the modification is called in the action `admin_menu` you can come just after, in order to correct the menu with some code like this :

```
add_action("admin_menu", function () {

    $parent_file = 'parent.php';
    $full_url = add_query_arg( 'action', 'action-name', admin_url( 'users.php' ) );


    global $submenu;


    // searching the last submenu
    $last = array_pop($submenu[$parent_file]);

    // correcting the URL
    $last[2] = $full_url;

    // replacing in the array
    $submenu[$parent_file][] = $last;

}, 20);
// default priority (used by the plugin) is 10, so I choose 20 to be sur that it comes after the plugin
```

Comment: I placed your code in the functions.php, but it not works, also no errors. If this helps: the effect must be seen in the admin dashboard.