# How to override theme's public static function inside of a trait?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, themes

I use a theme which has a public static function to display a part of a page like:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    public static function some_function() {
    ?>
        <div class="some_class">Some content</div>
    <?
    }
}
```

and the helper file looks like:

```
class Helper {
    use SomeTrait;
    // ...
}
```

I need to override the function in my plugin.

In the plugin I try the code:

```
/*
Plugin Name: MyPlugin
Description: -
Version: 1.0
Author: -
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

class Extra extends Helper {
    trait SomeTrait{
        function some_function() {
            ?>
            <div>Test</div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

But I receive the fatal error: *Class 'Helper' not found in ...*

---

**UPDATE**

If I try:

```
function my_function() {
    class Extra extends Helper {
        public static function some_function() {
            ?>
            <div>Test</div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_function' ); // with the 'after_theme_setup' the result is the same
```

I don't receive any errors, but my function doesn't override the existing one

Answer (score 0):

I believe plugins are loaded before the theme (see here ["plugins_loaded" vs "setup_theme"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request)) so the error is occurring because Helper has not loaded yet.

One thing you can try is to create a child theme and add the class override there (via functions.php).

You can also provide your override after the theme has loaded by hooking into "after_theme_setup" or "init". There are more details in this post here: [How to override a theme function (within a class) using a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173909/how-to-override-a-theme-function-within-a-class-using-a-plugin)

Comment: Thanks, I need only overriding by my plugin. See my update

Comment: Can you post the full code you're trying to override in the theme? Also, wouldn't you need to call `Extra->some_function();` in order for your override to execute?